# Can't attach local Javascript file to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, script-tag

I can't seem to attach my local Javascript file to the page:

```
<head>
<title>My Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">     </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="VideoGamesApp">

<div class="Main" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
       <p>{{test}}</p>
    </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src='C:/Application/Application.js'></script>
</body>
```

The script:

```
var app = angular.module('VideoGamesApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = "Success";
});
```

When I write the script directly in the page it works, but not when i link it with "src".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The src path is relative to the html file. If both are in the same directory, then try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='Application.js'></script>
```

if in a subdirectory

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='dirName/Application.js'></script>
```

if in a parent directory

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='../Application.js'></script>
```

However, make sure that the JS file is somewhere in the hierarchy of the root directory of your website, that is the root folder that your web server uses.

Comment: If it is up one directory ad 2 dots infront of the foward slash.   src='../Application.js'

Comment: It's in the same directory and 
    <script type="text/javascript" src='Application.js'></script>
isn't working. 
edit: However, the "{{test}}" isn't showing but "Success" isn't showing either